# template constructor overloading issue

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, constructor-overloading

I have a class template with three constructors and one of them is function template.

```
template<class T>
class TemplateOverLoading
{
public:
    TemplateOverLoading(void){};
    ~TemplateOverLoading(void){};
    //constructor that take reference
    TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, T& qValue )
        :   mName(qName),
            mValue( &qValue)
    {
        std::cout << "Reference -> "<< *mValue <<"\n";
    }

    //Template constructor that takes array
    template<class T, int N>
    TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, T (&t)[N])
        :   mName(qName),
            mValue(t)
    {
        std::cout << "Array ->\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            std::cout<< mValue[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //Other constructor that take pointer
    TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, T* qValue )
        :   mName(qName),
            mValue( qValue)
    {
        std::cout << "Pointer "<< *mValue <<"\n";
    }
private:
    T*               mValue;
    //T*              mValueArray;
    std::string&    mName;
};
```

From my application I need to distinguish between reference type/value, pointer and array and perform specific operation. Hence I decided to have to different constructors.

I am trying to invoke the constructor in the following manner:

```
int init(10);
int intArray[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
TemplateOverLoading<int> mInt(std::string("mInt"), init);    
TemplateOverLoading<int> mIntArray( std::string("mIntArray"), intArray );
```

The problem is if the constructor with the pointer is defined the array constructor is never invoked. However, if I comment that one out it prints the array as it should.

Output:

```
(when pointer constructor is present)
Reference -> 10
Pointer 0

(when pointer constructor is not present)
Reference -> 10
Array ->
0123456789
```

So syntactically it is possible and it is correct deducing the the array size N.

Obviously I am confusing the compiler when the array constructor is present. So instead of letting the compiler automatically deduce I tried to specify the template parameter for the array constructor to only find out unlike the regular function, template parameters cannot be specifically specified.

I thought of introducing a dummy parameter in the array constructor to differentiate the overloading but it doesn't seem nice.

Is there any other way to resolve this? Any clue appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your pointer constructor parameter to `T*& qValue`.

```
TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, T*& qValue )
    :   mName(qName),
        mValue( qValue)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer "<< *mValue <<"\n";
}
```

By making it a reference to a pointer, array-to-pointer decay is prevented and the array constructor is chosen.

Also, I don't see how your code compiles, I see many errors:

Your template constructor has a parameter `class T`, this conflicts with the `class T` of the class template:

```
template<class T, int N>
    TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, T (&t)[N])
```

This needs to be changed to something else than `class T`, for example `class U`:

```
template<class U, int N>
        TemplateOverLoading(std::string& qName, U (&t)[N])
```

Your constructors also take a **non-const** lvalue reference, non const reference cannot bind to temporaries, which you are passing in the constructor call, i.e. `std::string("mIntArray")`. You need to change it to `const std::string&` or take it by value. Also your member `std::string&    mName;` is a reference, you should remove the `&` there.

Comment: @Xymostech: A non-template is always a better match than a template, but if you make them all templates, then the better matching constructor will be chosen ([see example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2AggRp$5)).

Comment: converted as '@Jessse Good' said but it is giving me compilation error: **error C2668: 'TemplateOverLoading<T>::TemplateOverLoading' : ambiguous call to overloaded function with [T=int] templateoverloading.h(32): could be 'TemplateOverLoading<T>::TemplateOverLoading<int>(std::string &,U *)' with [T=int, U=int] or 'TemplateOverLoading<T>::TemplateOverLoading<int,10>(std::string &,T (&)[10])' with [T=int]**

Comment: @Jesse Good it seems different compiler interpret this differently. I am using VS2008 and the code I pasted earlier compiles. However, I have copy pasted the same code as you put in the liveworkspace it is still giving compilation error 2668 -> ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: @jazaman: No, your compiler was right, the compiler I was using had a bug. The code is ambiguous. Changing `U* qValue` to `const U* qValue` is one way to solve the problem (but then you can only pass `const int*` with constructor).

Comment: @jazaman: I thought of a good solution, see my updated answer.